# TensorFlow: Input to reshape is a tensor with 2099200 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 31

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm reviewing [PassGAN](https://github.com/Karlosse/PassGAN) project based on TensorFlow and, when I generate samples by the command:

```
python sample.py --input-dir pretrained --checkpoint pretrained/checkpoints/195000.ckpt --output gen_passwords.txt --batch-size 1024 --num-samples 1000000
```

I get an error containing the following statement:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 2099200 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 31
    [[{{node Reshape_1}}]]
```

This error is triggered when, on [sample.py](https://github.com/Karlosse/PassGAN/blob/master/sample.py) the generation of samples is run by `samples = session.run(fake_inputs)` where `fake_inputs = models.Generator(args.batch_size, args.seq_length, args.layer_dim, len(charmap))`. `models.Generator() is defined in [models.py](https://github.com/Karlosse/PassGAN/blob/master/models.py).

The `31` value in the error is given by the value of `len(charmap)`. In this case, `2099200` must be a multiple of `32` so I input `len(charmap)+1` as argument in `models.Generator()`.

If I run it again by the same command above, I get now the following error:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Input to reshape is a tensor with 2099200 values, but the requested shape has 327680
```

At this point, if I change the `batch_size`, both of the input to reshape and the requested shape will change.

How can I fix this issue related to the input to reshape and the requested shape in order to be equal?